# Can't install Ubuntu because it says I previously installed on a drive that was a usb drive how do I fix this?

Tags: system-installation

I previously installed Ubuntu on a USB drive. I have since lost it or deleted the data and when I go to try to install it says it is already installed on the usb drive letter. How can I fix this?

This is the error that I'm getting. I do not have the USB drive or it is deleted. I have 10-15 usb drives and have no clue which one it would be. I am using Wubi to try to install.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Not sure where I saw the drive letter but the link to the screen shot is below. I can't post the image since I do not have ten reputation points yet. The link to the error is below.

http://www.acrsol.com/photos/TEMP/ubuntuerror.jpg

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Its look like you have a grub entry which is created using bcdedit ?! Go to Windows control panel and check whether there is "Wubi uninstaller" menu or not. If it is there then use it to completely uninstall previous Ubuntu. Use CCleaner to clean the registry afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

> Its look like you have a grub entry which is created using bcdedit ?!
>   Go to Windows control panel and check whether there is "Wubi
>   uninstaller" menu or not. If it is there then use it to completely
>   uninstall previous Ubuntu. Use CCleaner to clean the registry
>   afterwards.

– [Curious Apprentice](/users/53649/curious-apprentice) May 4 at 2:37

Answer (score 0):

Just do a low-level format on that USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

with some download installs, windows installs from a temp folder (not the download location), it deletes the files after. Look in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp`, `%\AppData\%` is a hidden folder so you might need to change your `Folder options`. In `%\Temp` you can find `{7a113f87 ....` and delete it, then run your installation.